# Weighted Block Bootstrap

Tags: sampling, bootstrap

[image]

In this diagram (from '*An introduction to the Bootstrap*') the black circles represent the original time series while the white circles represent the sampled bootstrap realization.

This bootstrap makes it less likely to select data points at the very beginning or end of the sequence. Depending on the size of the data set, this can lead to problems if the value for **block length** is too large.

Is there some kind of **weighted sampling** of the blocks so that each data point is sampled with equal probability? Or is it common to simply prefer shorter block lengths?

*Note: I cannot use circular block bootstrap.*

Comment: I suppose it would depend upon the aspects of the time-series that you would hope to preserve in a bootstrapped resample. It most cases, I suspect the univariate aspects are preserved irrespective of block length, yet the autocorrelation diminishes with shorter blocks. That the data are correlated means that unequal sampling probabilities is actually *desirable*.

Comment: In fact, the undesirable trait is that, no matter what block length is chosen, the autocorrelation of the series cannot be preserved, neither for stationary *nor* for detrended time series. The bootstrap will always be somewhat less autocorrelated. The parametric bootstrap stands out as an immediate solution: just simulate the series.